# Proper way to correlate an OperationCanceledException to a CancellationToken

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, cancellation, cancellation-token

I'm using an async api which supports cancellation and I'm passing to that api a `CancellationToken` instance. As usual, if the cancellation is requested on the passed token, the api that I'm invoking will throws an `OperationCanceledException` (this is the standard cooperative cancellation pattern of the .NET framework).

I want to be able to catch the `OperationCanceledException` **if and only if** it is the exception raised due to the cancellation of the provided cancellation token.

The following code illustrates what I'm trying to achieve:

```
try 
{
    await _service.DoSomethingAsync(cancellationToken: token);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ex) when ( /* here I want a condition signifying that the OperationCanceledException is caused by the cancellation of the token object */)
{
    // avoid logging the exception: this is raised by design (cooperative cancellation)
    throw;
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred: {0}", ex.Message);
    throw;
}
```

For the exception filter of the code above I have basically two ideas:

- checking the `IsCancellationRequested` property on the `token` object: `when (token.IsCancellationRequested)`
- checking the `CancellationToken` property on the `ex` object: `when (ex.CancellationToken == token)`

What is the right way to do the check I want to perform ? Are the two ways showed above equivalent ? Is there a best practice ?

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: I know that the code showed above can be written in a more efficient way, because catching exceptions is an expensive operation. The best thing to do is probably removing the first `catch` block at all, and only catching an `Exception` if and only if it is not related with the cancellation of the `token` object. I'm aware of that, but that's not the point of my question. **I have written the code in the question that way only for clarity**, because the whole point of my question is how to properly correlate an `OperationCanceledException` with the `CancellationToken`which has caused the exception itself.

Comment: The former would make more sense, as both tokens may be cancelled

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to be able to catch the OperationCanceledException if and only if it is the exception raised due to the cancellation of the provided cancellation token.

You can't do this *exactly*, but you can "catch the canceled exception only if my provided token has been cancelled", which is usually good enough.

`when (token.IsCancellationRequested)` is what you want.

Don't check the `ex.CancellationToken`, because the method you're calling may be observing a linked cancellation token, which would be different than the one you provided.

Comment: thanks for the answer. If the api I'm calling is observing a linked cancellation token, then the `ex.CancellationToken` is actually **the linked one** and not the one that I'm providing from outside, right ?